# Are any denominations seeing AI as the 'beast which rises up out of the sea'?

Tags: eschatology, revelation, beast, artificial-intelligence

> By harnessing the power of AI and machine learning paired with the right data from satellites and beyond, our models are giving us a picture of the world we’ve never seen before. And it’s allowing us to make climate progress in a way some never believed possible.”

[Gavin McCormick, a co-founder of Climate Trace and executive director of environmental nonprofit WattTime](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2023/dec/03/greenhouse-gas-emissions-soar-with-china-us-and-india-most-at-fault)

Gavin McCormick contributed to COP28 and said the above at a time when it has just been stated that the US, China and India are most at fault in regard to soaring gas emissions, particularly of methane. (See the same link as above, as to that information.)

In the desperation to correct the climate situation, has humanity invented its own 'god' - a beast formed of the nations themselves, a conglomerate of all knowledge, a collusion of all expertise, and is this a present day manifestation of something that existed in a former day, but in a very different guise ?

Are any Christian denominations perceiving a danger as trust is beginning to be put in a 'living' form that is, effectively, the accumulation of knowledge and experience of humanity but without any input whatsoever from any other source - whether divine, heavenly or spiritual ?

I am interested in what any denominations might have said about this aspect of artificial intelligence and I would be particularly interested if there was a Protestant and Trinitarian source available.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/christians-fear-ai/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The November 2023 issue of *Evangelical Times* newspaper had an article on page 5 headed **"Artificial Intelligence is 'accelerating' the work of...Bible Translators"**. Although just reporting on one Bible Society, undoubtedly all of them will have latched on to this apparent advantage in speeding up the work of translating into the 3,742 languages currently in progress. I take this to refer to work done by various Protestant Bible Societies, but there is no single denomination attached to any of them. The report said,

> "Throughout history - from the 15th-century printing press to 21st-century smartphone apps - technology has been crucial. The advent of AI is set to have an incredible impact on Bible
> translation, enabling local Bible translators to produce high-quality
> translations quicker than ever. Mundane tasks are being sped up,
> allowing translation teams to focus more on the areas that require
> their human skill and insight. As a result, the time taken to
> translate the Bible is predicted to come down by up to half - without
> sacrificing quality! It means many more people will be able to access
> the good news of Jesus through the Scriptures much sooner."

Last week I e-mailed that particular Bible Society with a query about how, exactly, AI was being used, and still await their response. They do not represent any one denomination although they are staunchly Protestant and trinitarian.

However, ***this question asks if any denominations see AI as "the beast which rises up out of the sea"***. Daniel's vision speaks of four beasts coming up out of a churning sea (chapter 7) but there is a singular beast coming out of a churning, visionary sea in Revelation chapter 13, and it is this one which contains features of the four previous beasts but which has progressed beyond them to arise shortly before Jesus returns - this is the one sea-beast in question. The Bible states that such a mystical 'sea' is the churning sea of mankind - all the worldly nations in turmoil. I now quote from a leader of a Protestant, trinitarian fellowship (his book):

> "Considering that the first [sea] beast, the second [earth] beast,
> also called the false prophet, and both the whore and the city Babylon
> are not figures of actual beings, but of ideological conceptions or
> powers of the dragon it is all the more remarkable that Babylon should
> merit the greater space [in Revelation]. Why is this? Because neither
> Satan himself (spiritual and invisible in his nature) nor the two
> beasts, intangible creative concepts of the devil beyond the natural
> conception of man, assume any material form, meaning, or appeal to the
> lust of the flesh, the lust of the eyes, or the pride of life. Whereas
> such things are of the essence to the form taken by the mystical
> Babylon. Neither Satan nor the beasts appeal directly in such a way:
> all the appeal to mankind is manifested through Babylon the woman and
> Babylon the city. Grasp these concepts, and the dragon and his powers
> though invisible, become exposed by revelation... Revelation 13:1 -
> It has been shown that the seven heads of the [sea] beast indicate
> perfect earthly intelligence... the beast is a mystical figure
> depicting a creation of the mind and ingenuity of Satan." *The
> Revelation of Jesus Christ*, John Metcalfe, pages 444 & 468 http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Although this 1998 book (reprinted in 2022) does not mention AI, we are now in a position to see the link. AI is an invisible intelligence, a concept requiring human mind (to begin with). It began 70 years ago but is now taking invisible 'shape' as an animated thing in itself. All the nations are combining to pursue realising their vision of an ideological utopia that will require an invisible 'authority' to either allow desirable people in, or to keep undesirable people out.

We are already at the stage where AI is run by algorithms, initially designed by humans. The trouble is, AI is adding knowledge to its vast storehouse of information at such a phenomenal rate, it will soon surpass the sum total of human knowledge and decide within its own invisible systems what will happen. It will become *the* authority to which humanity must be subject (because they will lose control over it, as the invisible dragon giving power to those beasts purposes.)

There is much more that could be said, as I have spoken with, and read papers on this by Protestants who are trinitarians. But they do not represent any denomination/s. ***This means that the answer to the question is:***

**There doesn't seem to be a denominational stance because of looking in the wrong direction, so far.** They need to look for a visionary appreciation of the concepts written about in the book of the Revelation. Once Protestant, trinitarian denominations hear the prophetic voice that has started to warn Christians, just as voices alerted believers to invisible powers and authorities controlling the nations a few hundred years ago, then the shape-shifting invisible power of the dragon will be exposed in its modern guise - AI being the rising authority we will all have to bow to, else we won't be able to buy or sell; and (as always) some of those with the prophetic voice and vision will have to die as the wrath of the dragon behind it all is unleashed.

EDIT - After this Q and my A were posted, an item was published in *The Record* (the journal of The Free Church of Scotland, Edinburgh). The February 2024 edition had on page 35 the heading "Artificial Intelligence", written by the Rev. Roddie Rankine. It was a poem with a  most insightful warning about where A.I. is leading us into, also dealing with the climate situation. He has A.I. 'speaking' to us, with such lines as,

"I’ve said enough – don’t want you smart to the delusions of your heart... While you believe you’re in control, I am the master of your soul... I’ll prophesy the dreams I'll make reality... Inherit earth; have fun with genes. Who then will think computers odd, when my reign shows if man is God.”

There were 14 stanzas and nowhere was it said that A.I. is the "beast" in question, nor are such poems to be taken as Free Church policy or doctrine, but Christian individuals are beginning to sound the warning.

Answer (score -2):

**Short answer:** No.

**Longer answer:** The Antichrist *might* offer an alignment system as a solution to the AI problem, due to the fact that it is an existential risk to humanity along with war, poverty, and climate change, and the Book of Revelation describes the first horseman of the apocalypse as the bearer of solutions to all the world's problems. (Revelation 6:2) But he will most likely be an apostate bishop. And it is very likely that this pretense of AI will be quickly dropped as he focuses on making himself as the object of worship. Which in turn will be quickly dropped in order to focus on the destruction of Israel and her ethnoreligious group (for he will be the prince of antisemites).

"He will oppose and will exalt himself over everything that is called God or is worshiped, so that he sets himself up in God’s temple, proclaiming himself to be God." (2 Thessalonians 2:4 NIV)

Comment: My question was about denominational response. Are you telling me that you have full knowledge of all Christian denominations and you say categorically that none have the view that I have enquired about ?

Comment: According to David Stowe, samples are generally speaking representative of their superset population, so the survey I did of many Christian denominations and new Christian offshoot cults (JWs, Christian Science, Latter-Day Saints) allows me to say with high confidence that no, none of major ones do. Although a few house churches might.

Comment: @NigelJ I recommend you read the Book of Revelation. It is difficult to interpret, but rewarding. "I looked, and there before me was a white horse! Its rider held a bow, and he was given a crown, and he rode out as a conqueror bent on conquest." (Revelation 6:2) <- scriptural evidence that Antichrist will be a profferer of false solutions to world problems, including AI.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have been reading that astounding book since my conversion in 1967 at the age of sixteen. May I also recommend to yourself the book by John Metcalfe (all 650 pages of it) which describes the four main interpretations of the book (Historicist, Praeterist, Resumptive and Futurist) and then fully expounds the Resumptive demonstrating seven, increasingly spiritual, sweeps of visionary prophecy, repetitively revealing, seven times, the progression of history from Christ's ascension to the end of time and Christ's return. I asked for _denominational response._

Answer (score -2):

No, *AI* is not the *Sea Beast* prophesied in the book of Revelation.

1. If you read the verse closely then you will learn that the Sea Beast rises up out of the **sea** which means that this empire rises up out of the **world**. AI cannot be the sea beast because it rises up out of technologically advanced countries which are few.
2. The sea beast also has authority over every tribe and nation but AI does not.
3. The sea beast sits on seven mountains but AI does not.

As of today I am not aware of any denominations that interpret technological advancements to be Biblical entities.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not doctrinal, asking about the truth, or otherwise, of the interpretation. If you read the question closely, you will see that it asks 'Are there any denominations . . . . . . etc'. (I have already accepted an excellent answer to this question.